# Any way to customise YouTrack tickets created by Crashlytics

Tags: crashlytics, youtrack

I have set YouTrack integration from Crashlytics setting. It's creating tickets in YouTrack as per level set. But I also want to set some fields automatically in all those tickets created on YouTrack by Crashlytics.

Fields like - State of that ticket (new/open) and Version number of the app crashed.

Is there any way to do that programmatically through any script or settings?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of Crashlytics -> YouTrack integration details, but if you can somehow distinguish the issues created by this integration, you can then modify them by a YouTrack workflow.